# What is missing in Gym registration?

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I get

```
ValueError: xxx not found in gym registry, you maybe meant
```

when trying to register a custom environment in stable baselines 3. I tried the following command:

```
python train.py --algo tqc --env donkey-mountain-track-v0 --eval-freq -1 --save-freq 20000
```

The result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\donkeycar_sim\gym_donkeycar\rl-baselines3-zoo\train.py", line 161, in <module>
    raise ValueError(f"{env_id} not found in gym registry, you maybe meant {closest_match}?")
ValueError: donkey-mountain-track-v0 not found in gym registry, you maybe meant 'no close match found...'?
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you register the environment as well?

Answer (score 0):

This must be because you might not have edited the environment name in tqc.yml file under hyperparams folder in rl-baselines3-zoo

Just replace "donkey-generated-track-v0" with "donkey-mountain-track-v0" and it will be fine.